# how to click element before page is fully loaded with Selenium and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping

How can I make selenium click a button before the rest of the page loads. When I run this code it always waits until the entire page is loaded. I would like my scraper to be fast so I would prefer to avoid this.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

const myurl = "https://www.somewebsite.com";
driver.get(myurl);

myButton = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('some-button'));
myButton.click();
```

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188633/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-skip-the-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click-and-cont

Comment: I have tried executing JavaScript but unfortunately it still waits for a full page load